Does Dispelling Globe counteract a spell previously cast on a creature that moves into the globe?
Dispelling Globe (previously known as Globe of Invulnerability) has the following effect:

It attempts to counteract any spell from outside the globe whose area or targets enter into it, as if the globe were a dispel magic spell 1 rank lower than its actual spell rank.

The interaction is pretty clear for an attack cantrip targeting someone in the globe.
But what if a creature under the effect of a spell (such as Tailwind/Longstrider) walks into the Globe? Is there a counteract check?
What about an item under the effect of a spell (such as Ghostly Weapon) that is moved into the Globe?

They get affected by the globe
You have the text right there

It attempts to counteract any spell from outside the globe whose area or targets enter into it, as if the globe were a dispel magic spell 1 rank lower than its actual spell rank.

A creature under the influence of a spell such as tailwind is the target of that spell. ("Some spells allow you to directly target a creature, an object, or something that fits a more specific category.", CR, p. 304). As the spell's target enters into the sphere, the sphere tries to dispel the spell.
The same is the case for something like ghostly weapon, which as a touch spell also targets the weapon. ("A spell with a range of touch requires you to physically touch the target." CR, p. 304). As the target of the spell enters into the sphere, the sphere tries to dispel the spell.

I was reading the spell description as when the spell enters the Globe. Wouldn't your (probably correct) interpretation imply that attack cantrips cast from outside are NOT counteracted? Since there is no area, and the target (creature being attacked) is already inside the globe.

@AlexMillette That‘s a different question. Historically GoI did prevent all spell effects entering. If that is still the case under the latest wording is not clear to me, although I think its likely the intended way this should work.
